# Do we need a [blender] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's obsolete and it makes people think modelling related questions should go here. There's already a separate Blender SE for that.

In my opinion this tag should be separated into [blender-engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-engine) and [blender-file-format](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-file-format).

Comment: modelling related questions *can* go here, if they also relate to game development.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any reason to do anything about the [blender](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender) tag; Blender questions are on-topic here, just like Max or Maya questions.

Just because the Blender StackExchange site exists *does not* mean we automatically consider questions involving Blender off-topic.

It's possible that a user might be *better served* by having asked their Blender-related question on the Blender site, but as long as it's reasonably game-development related it's perfectly fine here.